# On free circle-ci plan it’s posible change php version?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, version, continuous-deployment, circleci

I need php `5.5.9` for a require of composer. But my current php version it's `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21`.

Does anybody know if is possible change the php version on `Free plan`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was use the 'circle.yml' file that should be placed on root of the project.

For my, this was the config:

```
machine:
  php:
    version: 5.5.9
```

More info here: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration